# I am facing this problem in gradle Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration

Tags: android, maven, kotlin, gradle, flexbox

I am facing the below problem in my multi-module app, my Gradle internet connection is active there is no problem there here is the errors.

the error stack:

```
   > Task :app:writeDebugSigningConfigVersions UP-TO-DATE
    
    FAILURE: Build completed with 9 failures.
    
    1: Task failed with an exception.
    -----------
    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
    > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
       > Could not find com.google.android:flexbox:1.1.1.
         Searched in the following locations:
           - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/flexbox/1.1.1/flexbox-1.1.1.pom
           - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/android/flexbox/1.1.1/flexbox-1.1.1.pom
         Required by:
             project :app > project :authentication > com.google.android.ads:mediation-test-suite:2.0.0
    
    * Try:
    Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
    
   Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.

Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find com.google.android:flexbox:1.1.1.

Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find com.google.android:flexbox:1.1.1.

Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.

Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find com.google.android:flexbox:1.1.1.

Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':authentication:debugCompileClasspath'.

Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find com.google.android:flexbox:1.1.1.

Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':authentication:debugCompileClasspath'.

Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.

Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find com.google.android:flexbox:1.1.1.

Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find com.google.android:flexbox:1.1.1.
```

Thanks for your help in advance.